how to read the mlir file and parse the string?
I am new to llvm.
I wanted to read the local mlir file, e.g., test.mlir as StringRef src and then parse them into MLIRContext. What's the best way to read such a file? Thanks!
static OwningOpRef<ModuleOp> parseFromString(StringRef src, MLIRContext *ctx) {
   ///.....
}


This is an old question but in case someone comes here. I have this code which returns a shared_ptr but you can customize it to suit your needs.
// MLIRModuleSerializer.h
class MLIRModuleSerializer {
public:
  // Constructor
  MLIRModuleSerializer(mlir::MLIRContext &context);

  // Load an MLIR module from a file
  mlir::LogicalResult load(const std::string &filename,
                           std::shared_ptr<mlir::ModuleOp> &module);

private:
  mlir::MLIRContext &context;
};

// MLIRModuleSerializer.cpp

// Constructor
MLIRModuleSerializer::MLIRModuleSerializer(mlir::MLIRContext &context)
    : context(context) {}

// Load an MLIR module from a file
mlir::LogicalResult
MLIRModuleSerializer::load(const std::string &filename,
                           std::shared_ptr<mlir::ModuleOp> &module) {
  llvm::ErrorOr<std::unique_ptr<llvm::MemoryBuffer>> fileOrErr =
      llvm::MemoryBuffer::getFileOrSTDIN(filename);
  if (std::error_code ec = fileOrErr.getError()) {
    llvm::errs() << "Could not open input file: " << ec.message() << "\n";
    return mlir::failure();
  }

  // Parse the input mlir.
  llvm::SourceMgr sourceMgr;
  sourceMgr.AddNewSourceBuffer(std::move(*fileOrErr), llvm::SMLoc());
  mlir::OwningOpRef<mlir::ModuleOp> owningModule =
      mlir::parseSourceFile<mlir::ModuleOp>(sourceMgr, &context);
  if (!owningModule) {
    llvm::errs() << "Error can't load file " << filename << "\n";
    return mlir::failure();
  }

  module = std::make_shared<mlir::ModuleOp>(owningModule.release());
  return mlir::success();
}



context is not defined here

@Tim - thanks for pointing that out. I've edited it to add the context variable.
